# How to define files which used on a page?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angularjs-directive, typescript

There is a project. Stack of technologies are asp.net + angularjs + typescript. Widely used angular directive. A page can have several directives (templates). Is it possible to know what are files exactly in the page without Visual Studio? For example, I open home page in browser and can see files which used. Or maybe I can write some code in Begin_Request and to trace for needed files. So, it is a task. Thanks.

Comment: you can put console.log('directive name') in the link function of each directive. You will see log results in the developer console (press F12) in browser.

Comment: Thank you MajoB. It is good idea. I think it over

Comment: how can anyone provide much help if you don't define your use case better?.. in others why do you need it

Comment: I would know what pages affected if I changed some directive.